# How to make libcurl read cookies from memory for a session?

Tags: curl, libcurl

I would like to have libcurl starting session with not cookies. 
One option is to use cookie file and remove it after the session ends.

Is it possible to use only libcurl properties for that?
like

```
curl_easy_setopt(CURL *handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, **""**);
```

for reading and for writing to memory

```
curl_easy_setopt(CURL *handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, **"-"**);
```

on the example above cookiejar should write the cookies to stdout, so I don't think it cookiefile will be able to locate those cookies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` to a non-existing file will enable libcurl's "cookie engine" with a blank cookie storage (in memory) to begin with.  It will then receive incoming cookies and send matching outgoing cookies accordingly using the cookies it has in memory.

`CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` should be set if you want libcurl to output (export if you will) the in-memory cookie storage to a file when you close the easy handle.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, so in order to use only in-memory cookies I just need to set the CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE to blank(""), therefore I don't really need to set CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR.   The option to enable the cookie engine using blank as a param for CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE was supported by CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE param from the beginning or it was developed after a few releases?